# Multi delete lines with no letter and line with starting letter N:

Tags: notepad++

I  need help with notepad ++. I want to delete all lines with no letter, and I want delete all lines with starting letter N:

[Here is picture what I want delete](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-hDpq8uMTSL4/UBBYJGC56NI/AAAAAAAAAbw/CZl_QiEiceI/w730-h509-k/Untitled+1.jpg)

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi. This is not a programming question, so shouldn't be on this site.

Comment: NB: The image no longer exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the picture that explains the problem no longer exists and so the question is not known.

Answer (score 1):

First in regular expression mode, replace `^N.*$` with nothing. Then, in extended mode replace `\r\n\r\n` with `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Find and replace dialog. Then you need to check Regular expression radio button.

For deleting empty lines in what to replace you have to write

`^\n` or `^\r\n` if you use windows-style newlines, and in with what to replace you have to write nothing.

For deleting lines that start with N you have to write

`^N.*\n` or `^N.*\r\n` if you use windows-style newlines, and in with what to replace you have to write nothing.